# PHP Syntax error caused by qutoes

Tags: php, string, syntax-error, double-quotes

I have been trying to mediate this error by playing around with the quotes but for some reason I just can't get passed the errors.

This is my code :

```
<form action='finish.php?id="<?=$row['session_id']?>"' method='post'>
  <textarea name='counselorcomments' rows='10' cols='50' placeholder='Please make sure to finish session before logging out! Also please be short and consise with your comments!'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' name='finish' value='Finish Session'>
  <input type='submit' name='additional' value =' Additional Counseling Needed'> 
</form>
```

This is the error :

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in
>   /var/www/DBFinaid/NewDBLogic/counselor.php on line 108, referer:
>   Https: my test server . com!

I know this problem stems from my low level understanding of single and double quotes so if I can request if there is a link as to where I can get a jump start on quotes then that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't think that this is the line that is giving you troubles. Is there any other PHP code on the page? Usually, this error is caused by forgetting a `}` character somewhere...

Comment: it was a unclosed else {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unexpected $end` usually means misplaced curly brace, an unclosed one.
Debug your code by removing large parts until the problem is eliminated. Then start adding them back and work out where it appears.

There is no syntax errors in the code you posted.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't end my else statement. I'm using aptana and that editor ends all quotes, braces, you name it. thanks a lot!